# Slice pandas multiindex dataframe using list of index values

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe that looks like

uid tid text

abc x   t1

bcd y   t2

*uid* and *tid* are the indexes. I have a list of *uid*s, and want to get the rows corresponding to the *uids* in that list, but keeping the 2nd level index values (tid). I want to do it without running any explicit loop. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data:

```
L = ['abc', 'bcd']

print (df)
         text
uid  tid     
abc  x     t1
abc1 x     t1
bcd  y     t2
```

1.[slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers)

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1 = df.loc[idx[L,:],:]
```

---

2.[`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) + mask with [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) + [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(L)]
```

---

3.[`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#special-use-of-the-operator-with-list-objects):

```
df1 = df.query('@L in uid')
```

```
print (df1)
        text
uid tid     
abc x     t1
bcd y     t2
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael. With approach one, I get 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)' error. But 2 works. Which is the most efficient? I have a huge data frame.

Comment: the fastest is sorting first by `df = df.sort_index()` and then use first method. `sorting` is explained ['In 97'](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex)